# Bootstrap 3 hidden-xs makes row narrower

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm experimenting with Bootstrap 3 responsive grids and am trying to make a column disappear from a row when the screen size is small. I can get the column to disappear but the whole row seems to get narrower as a result.

Here's my code that is giving me grief:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-1" align="center">
   Col1
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2" align="center">
   Col2
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-xs col-sm-6 col-md-5" align="center">
   Col3
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-xs col-sm-12 hidden-sm col-md-3 " align="center">
   Col4
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-1" align="center">
   Col5
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The columns Col4 and then Col3 disappear as the screen gets smaller but the row gets narrower at each removal (when compared to a header row row that doesn't change). I don't get why as I've made sure all the blocks add up to a width of 12 for each stage of the process. I though that maybe the col-xs-12 was the problem but removing this stops the column being removed at all and puts the removed column in with Col5!

I'm obviously missing 'something' but I can't find anything anywhere to help me - hopefully 
I will find enlightenment here.

Comment: You can also use `class="text-center"` to center-align bootstrap div content

Answer (score 58, accepted):

How does it work if you only are using visible-md at Col4 instead? Do you use the -lg at all? If not this might work.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-1" align="center">
            Col1
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2" align="center">
            Col2
        </div>
        <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-6 col-md-5" align="center">
            Col3
        </div>
        <div class="visible-md col-md-3 " align="center">
            Col4
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-1" align="center">
            Col5
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jimmie. To clarify I do use the -lg as well but you don't need to specify this - it will just stay that same as the md if you don't specify anything (I think I'm right there? - seems to work anyway!). The columns hide but if you compare it to another row in the same container that doesn't hide columns, the row that does gets narrower!

Answer (score -5):

```
.row {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

throw this in your CSS